# How to clear notification sent by shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, notifications, cinnamon

In my script I'm sending notification to the user and prompting him to enter some data. After that I want to clear notification that was sent earlier. The notification should stay in tray until user enters data.

Currently I'm using `notify-send`, but it could be cleared only by timeout.

What I want is something like that:

```
send-notification --title="Hey, enter some data pls" --id=999
prompt-to-enter-data
delete-notification --id=999
```

I'm using linux Mint 20. With cinnamon DE (v4.6.6).

`notify-osd` is not installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but not with `notify-send`. You need to talk to your desktop notifications service with a less specialized tool, like `gdbus`. It will allow you to call various methods from a shell.

<sup>An alternative is `dbus-send`, but it doesn't (at least for now) support the `variant` type needed by the `org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify` method. We will stick to `gdbus`.</sup>

Check [`man 1 gdbus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html). It includes an example which sends a notification:

> ```
> gdbus call --session \
>             --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
>             --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
>             --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
>             my_app_name \
>             42 \
>             gtk-dialog-info \
>             "The Summary" \
>             "Here's the body of the notification" \
>             [] \
>             {} \
>             5000
> ```

This should print `(uint32 42,)` where `42` is the notification ID. In fact the example specifies `42` explicitly, which means if there already is a notification with this exact ID then it will be replaced. To create a brand new notification specify `0`. A hardcoded ID (like `999` in your question) is possible, but what if the ID is already taken by some unrelated, possibly important notification? For this reason specify `0`, capture the output, isolate the new ID and use it with `org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification`.

Useful links:

- [`org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify`](https://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html#command-notify)
- [`org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification`](https://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html#command-close-notification)
- [standard icon names](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/latest/ar01s04.html)

Example script:

```
#!/bin/sh

tty="$(tty)"
id="$(gdbus call --session \
                 --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
                 --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
                 --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
                 my_script \
                 0 \
                 utilities-terminal \
                 "Response required" \
                 "Script awaiting input ($tty)." \
                 [] \
                 {} \
                 0
      )"
id="${id##* }"
id="${id%,)}"
printf 'Type here and hit Enter: '
read foo
>/dev/null gdbus call --session \
                      --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
                      --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
                      --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification \
                      "$id"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I've already lost all hope to get any answer for this question. :)

Comment: Id = 999 was just an example, it wasn't a requirement. Thanks again!

Comment: I really want a keyboard shortcut to close all open notifications -- do you know a way to get the ids of open notifications that weren't opened in this way?  Looks like it might not be possible.

Comment: @simon This is not how the site is supposed to work. Even if I knew a way, I wouldn't publish it *here*. [Ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask); include a link to this one if you think it provides context. Then you can lure me by linking to the new question in yet another comment here. I don't know the answer *yet* but *maybe* I will research the problem. Or maybe *somebody else* will help you.

Comment: Fair enough mate, I was going to suggest I could post a new question, but not to worry.

Comment: @simon No harm done.